# Compute the matrix with the standard basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $X$ be the left representation of $S_3$. Compute the matrix $X(132)$ in the standard basis  $S = {\{123,132,213,231,312,321}\}$.

attempt: In general if $G = S_3 = {\{\pi_1, \pi_2,..,\pi_6}\}$, then we have 
$\mathbb{C}[S_3] = {\{c_1\pi_1 + c_2\pi_2 + c_3\pi_3 + c_4\pi_4 + c_5\pi_5 + c_6\pi_6\ : c_i \in \mathbb{C} \forall i}\}$ .

$\mathbb{C}[S_3] = {\{c_1}123 + c_2132 + c_3213 + c_4231 + c_5312 + c_6321\ : c_i \in \mathbb{C} \forall i$} is the standard basis.

Then let $\pi = (132)$.

Any ideas and feedback to  help me would really help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the name standard basis.

Write an empty matrix of size $6\times 6$ ( order of $S_3$ is 6). For this matrix give headings to the rows and columns as below:  Row headings should be the elements of $S_3$ (in some order). Column headings should also be the same in the same order used for the rows.

Let us fill up the matrix with numbers.
Imagine writing the group multiplication table, but don't do that. Instead do this: multiply every column heading by 123 (as in your question) using the group law of $S_3$. Go down the column and put 1 in the row whose heading is the product of the multiplication, and put zero everywhere else in the column.

DO this for every column. Thats all. (If you had done that right you would have got a variant of identity matrix: i.e, its columns permuted).

Now for the nomenclature: Better name would have the natural basis. Standard basis is the name used when working with co-ordinates.

Comment: This reminds of a cayley table. When I multiply every column heading by 123 using the law of S_3. Would I multiply 123 as (123)(123), (123)(132), (123)(213),...and so on ? I would multiply them as regular permutations? So for example (123)(132) = e?

Comment: Read the paragraph starting "Let us.." in my answer above.  This is already covered there. I have said multiply using the group law. That means composition of permutations.